# Combine array values to subarray with their sibling values

Tags: php, arrays

I have this multidimensional array (screenshot). I would like to combine the "day" values in a new array in the current array structure (in the "week_days" array).

[image: arrays]

The desired result woud be:

```
$facilities array() -> array('weekdays') -> array('maandag') -> values "opening_hours", "closing_hours", "extra_info"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
 $fname=array("Peter","Ben","Joe");
 $age=array("35","37","43");

 $c=array_combine($fname,$age);
 print_r($c);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but I cannot get it to work with your technique.

When I use:
$weekday = array( "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Tuesday");
$weekday_items = array( array("item1","item1","item1"), array("item2","item2","item2"), array("item3","item3","item3"), array("item4","item4","item4"));
$c = array_combine( $weekday, $weekday_items );

I cannot see all data.